# Limiting input on node title and plain text area fields

Tags: 8

Is there a way to add a character limit on node title and plain textarea fields in Drupal 8? I don't want to use the Title module.

Comment: My first guess would be hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(). Tried this one?

Comment: I was looking more for a solution that uses Javascript too, that adds character limit count and prevents input when reached. Server side validation would be second.

Comment: Didn't use it myself yet in D8, but worked for me in D7 before: https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the beta version of the [Maxlength](https://www.drupal.org/project/maxlength) module which can be applied to built-in fields as well custom text fields.  The [Maxlength](https://www.drupal.org/project/maxlength) module allows you to set maximum length of any field; one option includes showing a javascript character countdown on the edit forms next to the applicable fields.

[image: character countdown indicator]

You could also take the js library this module is based off of and apply with the `hook_form_alter` approach.

Comment: This worked. I simply did not want to use the title module and have to redo a bunch of config and templates.